# Update quantity stock after save Sales order

Tags: crm, vtiger

I want update quantity stock after save Sale Order (deduct (-)) (such as Invoice (-) or Purchase Order (+)).

I've already tried a workflow following the example of the one done in the invoices but it doesn't work. I suppose we need to change the code.

deductFromProductStock($product_id,$updated_qty)
addToProductStock($productId,$qty)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update function as per your conditions which has been written in

> \include\utils\InventoryUtils.php

```
function updateStk($product_id,$qty,$mode,$ext_prod_arr,$module)
{
    global $log;
    $log->debug("Entering updateStk(".$product_id.",".$qty.",".$mode.",".$ext_prod_arr.",".$module.") method ...");
    global $adb;
    global $current_user;

    $log->debug("Inside updateStk function, module=".$module);
    $log->debug("Product Id = $product_id & Qty = $qty");

    $prod_name = getProductName($product_id);
    $qtyinstk= getProductQtyInStock($product_id);
    $log->debug("Prd Qty in Stock ".$qtyinstk);

    // Original $upd_qty = $qtyinstk-$qty;  

    // Customization start
    if($module == 'Invoice'){

    }else if($module == 'SalesOrder'){

    }else{
        $upd_qty = $qtyinstk-$qty;
    }
   //  Customization end
    sendPrdStckMail($product_id,$upd_qty,$prod_name,$qtyinstk,$qty,$module);

    $log->debug("Exiting updateStk method ...");
}
```